# Is there a way to include a current branch name variable in linux command prompt?

Tags: linux, git, command-line, branch

I have to do a repetitive work that includes introduce a lot of commands like:

- git pull upstream client
- git push upstream client
- git pull origin client
- git pull upstream client2
- git push upstream client2
- git pull origin client2
- ...

I was wondering if is there anyway to do something like this:

git pull **current_branch**

and when I push enter what the system receives is:

git pull **client**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
`git pull $(git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2)`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @AngelQuesada and I advise you to create a git alias for this command line.

Comment: Rather than piping the output of `git branch` through several more commands, consider running `git rev-parse --abbrev-rev HEAD`.

Comment: @torek, this gives me what seems to be commit id... like `52e6ac6e35df0e98f6cb7043b2efd529b72ae9ed`

Comment: @AlexeyMints Oops, sorry, typo, `abbrev-rev` should read `abbrev-ref` (lowercase F, not lowercase V). I make a lot of typos so I had actually tested this before commenting, but then failed to cut-and-paste it, and typo-ed the comment!

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative for this big commands what I understand is create alias, you can follow this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/alias-command-in-linux-with-examples/).